# Uploading large size of files of 140MB+ erroring in Github

Tags: github

I have a project (around 2GB) that contains large size of files (e.g.140MB), which cannot be uploaded to GitHub using its free account.

https://github.com/

Is there a way around this?

https://wersm.com/you-can-now-upload-videos-to-github/

Comment: Have you checked to see what you're permitted to do with a free account? If it does not include uploading files of that size, then the only way around it is to upgrade to a paid account.

Comment: What exact message are you seeing when trying to perform this operation?  Can you copy and paste it as a code block into your question?

Answer (score 1):

You would:

- either need to [activate LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) (see "[Configuring Git Large File Storage](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/versioning-large-files/configuring-git-large-file-storage)" on GitHub), but there [are limits in place](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/versioning-large-files/about-storage-and-bandwidth-usage)
- or split your file in smaller files (using a [file splitter](https://github.com/dubasdey/File-Splitter)), and push them individually